# Qual è il significato di "modula"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Natale a Marradi: l'ultimo Natale di Dino Campana*, di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto:

> Dentro al fascicolo c'era anche la «**modula**», che io poi ho pubblicato,  del 1909: in cui l'ufficiale sanitario del comune di Marradi, dottor Pellegrini, parlava di «alcolismo» e scriveva: «Il malato ha un odio speciale colla sua mamma, che è dovuta andar via di casa». Dalla **modula** al fascicolo rimbalzava quella diagnosi di «demenza precoce», che nei fascicoli dei matti era una delle formule piú ricorrenti e che dovrebbe servirci ancora oggi, per interpretare la vicenda di Dino Campana dal punto di vista clinico.

Non capisco il significato di "modula" in questo brano. L'ho cercato, ma non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ho trovato qui http://www.dizy.com/it/voce/modula questa definizione (Dizionario Tommaseo-Bellini del 1865-1879):

> **Modula** - [T.] S. f. Modello di scritto, per lo più breve, che debba Servire di documento, e che molti debbano ricopiare e sottoscrivere, concepito con le formole stesse per ch'abbia valore e non accadano sbagli. T. Modula d'una ricevuta. Femm. Siccome Moda da Modo. Non è del ling. Fare stampare la modula delle ricevute. – Module de' registri.

In pratica, lo stesso significato che oggi si dà al sostantivo "modulo":

> Formulario per la stesura di scritture determinate nell'ambito di una amministrazione pubblica o privata.

Dal testo mi sembra si parli di una specie di referto medico, magari stampato con spazi appositi da compilare.

Comment: Aggiungo, a completamento, che qui (https://books.google.it/books?id=PgA5iRY4nwEC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=modula+medica+vassalli+campana&source=bl&ots=S5PG6W-qo9&sig=_JEVPAVmtTJPFq5Ojxc_enId7Jw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivhYD_zJvXAhXMzRoKHQeXC2IQ6AEIYjAK#v=onepage&q=modula%20medica%20vassalli%20campana&f=false) si riproduce la modula, che è presente anche in un altro libro di Vassalli dedicato a Campana (*La notte della cometa*).